# How to use a video link from Firebase using json

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

export I m new in android so I don't anyhow to use this type of code in firebase. Below is my video link URL and I want to use it from firebase how can I do it please give me solution step by step because I m new in android project. thank you. here is video URL of mine `public

```
class playUtils {
    public static String[] videoUrls = {
            "http://112.253.22.163/4/p/p/q/v/ppqvlatwcebccqgrthiutjkityurza/hc.yinyuetai.com/59EC014EDDFE31808075899973863AAD.flv",
          "http://112.253.22.162/7/i/u/l/x/iulxxctvtlkdvznykfxqbftlwlvfdk/hc.yinyuetai.com/010C014EBF2B4B726D9D67F0BB236F6D.flv",
            "http://112.253.22.159/30/u/h/c/t/uhcthkfakxfueltyfrickugkkshedl/hc.yinyuetai.com/29A801589BED77C3D62884A3A15BA1F3.mp4",
            "http://112.253.22.164/4/a/q/t/z/aqtzkpyhsvnomtvjbskpjjkkyjeaaq/hc.yinyuetai.com/0EAD0158BD54A2F9F242E02065A966C2.mp4",
            "http://112.253.22.157/19/f/k/n/n/fknntmnmqvxxwomhukhftbjwrtmyci/hc.yinyuetai.com/45580153801E6B6083057A09E1811AA1.flv",
            "http://112.253.22.163/4/u/x/o/t/uxotdanllblkoxoegkthfpapivsywh/hc.yinyuetai.com/E2B60155AAA1AD8BD01A027BCB2540DE.flv",
            "http://112.253.22.162/5/k/s/a/r/ksarzmxsvukrlrlrncyqgqvguwgnww/hc.yinyuetai.com/BA710157626FB47F1B68C35E974120C7.flv",
            "http://112.253.22.156/14/j/s/s/d/jssdpypuuzgutqiolfvbxizywfjzjd/hc.yinyuetai.com/F9640146F51C894E3B31592989D7AE28.flv",
            "http://220.194.199.186/1/a/o/i/q/aoiqwkcqlcyqmhyaprtbhafndapzoe/hc.yinyuetai.com/70FD014F061C972D24F5EDE5381BE543.flv",
            "http://112.253.22.162/4/d/p/k/c/dpkcdjdhtzzfntsuoxhozwayhjvwke/hc.yinyuetai.com/ED44014EF18FF6700FBF10169A21144E.flv"};
`
after that here is video thumbnail `public static String[] videoThumbs = {
            "http://img3.yytcdn.com/video/mv/140108/850708/D81901436FF172396A44128BAC8C3707_240x135.jpeg",`
and title is here ` public static String[] videoTitles = {
            "B.B.B(Big Baby Baby)",`
```

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should only be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it.

Answer (score 1):

use Exoplayer to play from the link(Uri).

This is the code to stream the video.

```
private void initializePlayer() {
     Uri uri = Uri.parse(/*your video link here*/);
     MediaSource mediaSource = buildMediaSource(uri);
     player.prepare(mediaSource, true, false);
}
```

Find more about Exoplayer here. https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/exoplayer-intro/#2

Comment: Exoplayer will be used for streaming of media. you can just go through this tutorial/codelab and you will get to know how to add it in android project and use it to parse video/audio as well.

Comment: @K.DKamalDhital this is not a full code, but you can find it online anywhere by searching "how to parse video using exoplayer from a uri." this is just a reference. also you can use this codelab for adding library and how to use it to stream audio and video.